# Detecting edge only in particular portion of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to detect the edge only in the red marked region as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: How are you going to specify that red region ? Do you have some coordinates, or a mask image, or what ?

Comment: I drew it in piant for your identification

Comment: Yes, but how do you plan to identify it in your program ?

Comment: @user764909: read up on [ROI-based processing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f19-14453.html)

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions. I assume that the red region is input by mouse and that you now have a mask of the region that you want to include in the edge search.

My proposed algorithm

```
1. Do Edge detection
2. Write your own Hough routine but only count edges if they should be included according to the mask. 
3. Pick the edge with the best score in the Hough space.
```

Of course you don't need to run the edge detection on the complete image but if you don't make sure that you handle the border of your search area (so you don't get edges there). Simply mirroring the area might work.

---

### Update

Okay, different approach:

Use the `hough` routines in matlab. `houghlines`, `hough`, `houghpeaks` are the relevant functions. If only one line intersects your region of interest, you are done. The line is the result you want.

If more than one line intersect the region of interest, you need to do a bit more. I'd suggest counting the number of pixels along the line that are within the ROI. So, if the line intersects the ROI for 10 pixels, that line's score is 10. Do this for all lines and then pick the line with the highest score.

Note that none of the approaches are optimized for speed. However, they are easy to understand.

Comment: user764909, No, I won't. Type `help hough`, `help houghlines`, `help houghpeaks` in Matlab. Run the examples try to understand it. Of course there is also a Wikipedia article on Hough transform. If you don't understand it or have nobody to explain it to you, ask again in three days.

Comment: Sorry to say this Iam really new to Matlab...I done edge detction for the image but I'm unable to write  my own hough transform

Comment: Did you try matlab's hough tranform? `help houghlines` will tell you how to use your picture and overlay the detected lines. Try that for a start.

Comment: ..thanks for ur suggestion I tried  and result image I got is                                                   (http://tinypic.com/r/2yuezkk/7)

Comment: Good. Can you get access to the individual lines? Go through each line, and see if it is in your marked region. (Maybe count how many points of the line are in the 'good' region and then use the line with the highest count)

Comment: Only one line is in my required region.What is line with highest count?I'm not getting how to select this required line.Can ypu pleasxe explain it more clearly

Comment: Can I be able to get the edge only in required portion using these line?

Comment: "Only one line is in my required region." Well, that's it. You found it. Done.

Comment: No..My requirement is to detect the edge along that line only.So how can I extract the edge along that individual line leaving everything else

Comment: If you know the angle of the camera and the roll(?), you could identify the line along the edge of the sheet by selecting the one which has a minimum length and subtends a narrow range of angles with the horizontal. You could then define an image mask using the coordinates of this line (maybe just a bounding box) and then do your edge detection in that region. You should explain in more detail what you are trying to do in the question. Are the camera and the scene always fixed? if so you could just hard code the region of interest.