# selecting particular region of image for filtering

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Am trying to extract the red portion of image as shown in the link image

http://tinypic.com/r/2qntaip/7

I worked out like this

```
RGB = imread('Frame 0233.jpeg');
RGB =im2double(RGB );
img = rgb2gray(RGB);
n=[2 -1 -1;-1 2 -1;-1 -1 2];%detecting -45 degree lines in image
pout_adapthisteq = adapthisteq(img);
a3 = imfilter(pout_adapthisteq,n);
figure(1),imshow(a3);
```

Got the result image like this  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ad1zn&s=7

Can anyone help me to extract the line only in the red portion

Comment: You could try using `edge` to detect edges, and then dilate with a 105 degree linear structuring element.

Comment: This is the same image as in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672048/detecting-edge-only-in-particular-portion-of-image)

Comment: Detecting edges and then using dilate with a 105 degree linear structuring element is not working...

Comment: You posted this question before using another username

Comment: For mode answers go to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: But my actual need is to apply the high pass filter for the line inside red portion of the image  in MATLAB.                               So how to do highpass filtering for the lonie only inside the red portion......

Comment: @Varsha I showed how to build a mask for extracting that portion. After that you can manipulate the area content as you wish. Or perhaps I don't understand your question ...